# Meteor - layoutTemplate in RouteController.extend in package.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have problem with iron-router controllers in package.
My code:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('registration.index', {path: '/registration'});
});


RegistrationIndexController = RouteController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: 'IntranetLayoutSimple'
  ...
});
```

LayoutTemplate not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating new route controllers inside package and want to use them in main app, remember to export it, e.g.:

`api.export('RegistrationIndexController', ['client', 'server']);` in package.js